# Tokenizing a String

Tags: c++, string, struct, stream, token

What I'm trying to do is input a date following this format `Wednesday  7:05 PM` Then separate it into tokens to put in a struct i have. My main problem is the stringstream object i am using doesn't remove the already inputted string from the input buffer so on my second check for hours it fails because its inputting something of type char into an unsigned. How do i fix this? Also if you have any advice on me cleaning up the code i'd appreciate it.

```
struct Time{
        //  always in [0, 6]:
        //  0 means Sunday, 1 means Monday, ... , 6 means Saturday
    unsigned day;
        //  false means at or after midnight, and before the following noon (AM)
        //  true means at or after noon, and before the following midnight (PM)
    bool pm;
    unsigned hour;      //  in [1, 12], e.g. 12 for 12 o’clock
    unsigned minute;    //  in [0, 59]
};  //  struct Time

const string dayar[]={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

void input( Time & time ){
    string str, day, pm;
    unsigned hr, min;
    getline(cin,str);
    istringstream sin(str);
    cout<<str.length();
    for(unsigned i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        if(str[i]==':')
            str[i]=' ';
    }
    if(!(sin>>day)){
        die("AHHHHH!!! WHERE'S THE INPUT?!?!?!");
    }else{
        for(unsigned i=0; i<7; i++){
            if(day==dayar[i]){
                time.day=i;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!(sin>>hr)){
        die("AHHHHH!!! WHERE'S THE INPUT?!?!?!");
    }else{
        if(hr<1 || hr>12){
            die("THAT NUMBER AIN'T A REAL HOUR!!");
        }else{
            time.hour=hr;
        }
    }
    if(!(sin>>min)){
        die("AHHHHH!!! WHERE'S THE INPUT?!?!?!");
    }else{
        if(min<0 || min>59){
            die("THAT NUMBER AIN'T A REAL HOUR!!");
        }else{
            time.minute=min;
        }
    }
    if(!(sin>>pm)){
        die("AHHHHH!!! WHERE'S THE INPUT?!?!?!");
    }else{
        if(pm!="PM" || pm!="AM"){
            die("THAT NUMBER AIN'T A REAL HOUR!!");
        }else{
            pm=="PM"?time.pm=true:time.pm=false;
        }
    }
}

bool die(const char *msg){
    cout<<msg;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing that out. My apologies

Comment: Your use of the `?:` operator for getting AM or PM is unusual, normally it's used like this: `time.pm = (pm == "PM") ? true : false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you wouldn't read the values in one statement.  Something like this:

```
// Map day names to day number
map<string,unsigned> days;
for( unsigned i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) days[dayar[i]] = i;

bool ParseTime( const string& str, Time& time )
{
    bool valid = false;
    istringstream sin(str);

    string day, pm;
    unsigned hour, minute;  // Because unsigned, we don't bother to test >= 0
    char colon;

    if( sin >> day >> hour >> colon >> minute >> pm )
    {
        // Sanity test...
        valid = (days.find(day) != days.end())
             && (hour >= 1 && hour <= 12)
             && (colon == ':')
             && (minute < 60)
             && (pm == 'AM' || pm == 'PM');
    }

    if( !valid ) return false;

    time.day = days[day];
    time.hour = hour;
    time.minute = minute;
    time.pm = (pm == 'PM');

    return true;
}
```

I mean, if you wanna squawk about every conceivable date parsing error then go ahead! =)  But it just makes for cluttered code that's hard to follow.

Comment: O_O .....thank....so much. That is soooooo much cleaner thank what I was doing. Actually I just realized right before you posted this that i should have parsed the string to the proper type for the next variable. I think i'm going to go with your method though :P

Comment: Whoops, I wrote it as if it was 24-hour...  You get the idea though.  Just need to change the hour test to `hour >= 1 && hour <= 12`.

Answer (score 3):

When you change the colon to a space you change the string alright, but you don't change what's been buffered by the input stream.

Change the colon *before* declaring the input stream.

Also, there are better and more "C++-ish" ways to do that, using e.g. [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm>

// ...

std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
    [](const char c){ return (c == ':' ? ' ' : c); });
```

Comment: i understand that which is why i remove the colon and replace it with a whitespace shortly after i initialize istringstream.

Comment: @NimaGanjehloo Saw that too late. However, updated my answer with another problem.

Comment: ahhh thanks for pointing that out :P I'm not exactly sure what transform does. I think I'll try to mess around with it before I start using it. Appreciate the suggestion tho. Do you happen to know anything about how to remove w/e has already been read from the stream? That's the only thing keeping this from working :/

Comment: @NimaGanjehloo I'm not sure what you mean by "remove w/e has already been read from the stream"? If something has been read from a stream, it can't be read again unless you use e.g. [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg).

Comment: i just realized i wasn't parsing my string to the proper datatype to the next variable